# how to layout two div elements side-by-side

Tags: html, css

This seems like it has to be about the most beginner-level HTML question possible. I would like to layout some div elements like so

[image]

But when I try to do that with HTML like so

```html
<style>
  .outer-container {
    border: 8px solid red;
  }

  .my-header {
    /* border: 4px solid blue; */
    display: flex;
    font-size: medium;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .my-row {
    border: 3px solid orange;
    flex-direction: row;
  }

  .my-row-label {
    border: 2px solid orchid;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .my-row-value {
    border: 2px solid lime;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
</style>

<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="my-header">
    A Title
  </div>
  <div class="my-row">
    <div class="my-row-label">
      Row 1
    </div>
    <div class="my-row-value">
      Value 1
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="my-row">
    <div class="my-row-label">
      Row 2
    </div>
    <div class="my-row-value">
      Value 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the row-label and row-value classes stack vertically instead of going left-to-right inside the rows. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You must set display flex on your row.

Comment: what @cloned said. Here's a fiddle showing it: https://jsfiddle.net/bradberkobien/7w8p2dje/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There 2 ways to do it. Either with the use of a CSS Grid or with the use of Flexboxes.

CSS-Grid:
You predefine a grid. In this case with 2 columns `grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);`. The header span the entire width by using `grid-column: span 2;`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

#header {
  min-height: 30px;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.content {
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="header">Header</div>
  <div class="content">Content 1</div>
  <div class="content">Content 2</div>
  <div class="content">Content 3</div>
  <div class="content">Content 4</div>
</body>
```

Flexboxes:
Here you wrap the content boxes into a flex wrapper. The content is calculated with space-between incl. the border thickness and as such fit perfectly.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}

#header,
.flex div{
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

#header {
  min-height: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.content {
  min-height: 50px;
  width: calc(50% - 14.5px);
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="header">Header</div>
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="content">Content 1</div>
    <div class="content">Content 2</div>
    <div class="content">Content 3</div>
    <div class="content">Content 4</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: adding `class=flex` to the row container does what I want, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here 
You have to use `grid-row` and `grid-column` if you learned these it's a easy to make this kind of layout.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  border: 2px solid black;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.container div {
  min-height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.box1 {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <div class="box3"></div>
  <div class="box4"></div>
  <div class="box5"></div>
</div>
```

Let me know if it doesn't work for you.[Also link of my codepen](https://codepen.io/jv18creator/pen/OJXwZKK?editors=1100)

Comment: I suggested an edit for you, fixing your grid and shorting the CSS code by 2/3. And allowing it to work if more content boxes are added.

Comment: @tacoshy thank you for your time and efforts. Could you share me any documentation or youtube video on this kind of advanced css grid?

Comment: not really an advanced css grid. just a normal css grid kept simply and short. You dont need to declare its exact column position, they align themself. All you need it to tell the header to span both columns with `grid-column: span 2;` then, you dont need to list every box you have like `box1, box2, box3...`. They have all one thing in common, they are childrens of the `.container`. So you adress them all with `.container div`. No need to list everything. Last but not least, the grid items dont need a margin. Thats what you have `grid-gap` for aswell as as a padding of the grid-container.

Comment: for  a complete guide: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/ 

Firefox documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout